# Transistor driven switch for optoisolator PC817

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, circuit-analysis, analog

I am using a**ATMEGA328P-AU** for a project,

I am using 5volt 3Amp SMPS to power the microcontroller circuit,
I want to trigger the optoisolator from I/O pin of microcontroller but when i connected the output pin to PC817 the controller was unable to trigger - I suspect due to low current. I want to try a new circuit with a BC547 transistor, I have attached the image of the circuit.
[image]

** Questions: **
1.Will this circuit be able to trigger*Turn ON* the optoisolator?

2.If yes, What should be the values of the resistances and why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Depends. What’s on the other side of R1? Also, why complicate things with an PNP when you can low side NPN switch the optocoupler?

Comment: What does R2 do ?

Answer (score 1):

As PC817 consists of an LED and photo transistor, you can Control it with controller pin. Micro controller pin can source sufficient current to PC817, you don't need transistor. Measure O/p voltage of controller output pin. Are you correctly setting PIN as output. DDRX.n should High if you want to set it as o/p(x is port,n is Pin). Show your complete schematic and code so I can guide you.
For your reference visit **[optocoupler interfacing with avr pic and 8051 microcontroller](http://microcontrollerslab.com/optocoupler-interfacing-with-avr-pic-and-8051/#PC817_optocoupler_nbspinterfacing_with_avr)**